# what is the value of a correct to the nearest integer

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

[image]

This is an A-Level past paper question statistics and probability I managed to solve the first bit I  cant seem to figure this out because i have no teacher I don't know who to ask I would really appreciate any help. Thank you
[image] This is the mark scheme but I don't understand the steps and whats going on.

Comment: Hi Sara: your question is more likely to receive focused and useful attention if you kindly explain your working and thought processes up to the point where you got stuck, or even just ideas about what you think the right approach might be.

Comment: @Poo2uhaha this thing is I don't know I have never seen a question as such. but I will link the mark scheme but I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the upper limit of a confidence interval for proportions  $$p\pm z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$  where p is the sample proportion and n the sample size. For your example $p=\frac{6}{60} = 0.1$ for the sample size n = 60.

For a 95% confidence interval 5% of values are outside the interval -z to z, which means 2.5% of values are greater than z i.e. $P(Z>z) = 0.025$. In the Normal Table we look up $P(Z<z) = 0.975$ and see z is 1.96.  Solving the first equation for z in the sample answer you get z = 1.291. Going to the normal table, this goes with a probability value of 0.9015, near enough. This then corresponds to P(-1.291<Z<1.291) = 0.8 or $\alpha = 80%$